# Can someone help me identify this cloud formation?

Tags: meteorology, clouds

These pictures were taken today in Oklahoma City and I am both baffled and curious as to what formation this may be. I was wondering if anyone had any idea?

[image: unknown cloud 1]

[image: unknown cloud 2]

Thank you!

Comment: About what time will help in sourcing radar and satellite data to match.  You're talking about the wide arc, yes?

Comment: It appears to me to possibly be either a gravity wave or an outflow boundary.  As @JeopardyTempest indicated, satellite and radar data would help.  If you don't know where to find that information, you could give us a date and approximate time and we may be able to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after a bit of research, I stumbled upon the following image:

[image: copyright Roger Edwards]

This is from a blog of two storm chasers Roger and Elke who I believe witnessed the same cloud formation as you. In the following link:

```
http://stormeyes.org/latest/tag/left-moving-supercell/
```

**They refer to the formation as a 'rear flank arc cloud'.**

So in conclusion I believe, the formation is **a kind of arcus cloud**. You can learn more about arcus clouds on wikipedia by following the link:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arcus_cloud
```

I hope I have been of help.

Comment: Useful searching... but though it may or may not be an [arc cloud](http://glossary.ametsoc.org/wiki/Arc_cloud), it does not appear to be associated with any storm structure such as would entail a [rear-flank downdraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rear_flank_downdraft).  Thanks for the input!

Comment: @JeopardyTempest - to me it looks like a Arcus cloud - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arcus_cloud.

Comment: And these are common in gust fronts and they are sometimes known as shelf clouds.